# Загрузить blob фото в FireBird через php

Tags: php, база-данных, firebird

как загрузить Blob изображение в Firebird через Php?

```
        $imgSrc='Desert.jpg';
    $img_src = $imgSrc;
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($img_src, "r"), filesize($img_src));
    $img_str = base64_encode($imgbinary); 


    $blh = ibase_blob_create($this->db);   
    ibase_blob_add($blh, $imgSrc);
    $blobid = ibase_blob_close($blh);

    print_r($blobid);
    $row = false;
    /*$fd = fopen('Desert.jpg', 'r');
    $blob = ibase_blob_import($fd);
    fclose($fd); */
    $query = ibase_query($this->db, "INSERT INTO \"ud_ab\" (FILES) VALUES (?)", $blobid ) or die(ibase_errmsg());
    if($query) $row = true; 
    return $row;
```

Ничего из этого не помогает

Comment: Как именно ничего не работает? Вы получаете ошибку выполнения скрипта, в базе записывается не то, что вы ожидаете или вообще ничего не происходит? Выполняется ли коммит?

Comment: В базу записывается Base64 код. А не сам файл. Через c# если добавить изображение то. оно ставится сразу. можно открыть и посмотреть. А через php не получается. Может я что не атк делаю?

Comment: Вы же сами вызываете base64_encode($imgbinary), поэтому и записывается Base64

Comment: Я из андроид приложения отправляю изображение в base64, а на сервере обратно кодирую. С этим вопросом разобрался. Пришлось сохранить изображение на сервере, потом сохранить его в базе и после успешного сохранения удалить с сервера. Спасибо всем кто отозвался